# Windows Batch File Rename Multiple Periods

Tags: windows, batch, xxcopy

I am simply basically trying to copy a file such as X.TWO.THREE to DATE.X.TWO.THREE. X is a constant while the date will be added in the future.  For now I was using a constant for that as well. When I trying to rename the file such as:

```
xcopy C:\test\X.??????.?????? C:\test2\DATE.X.??????.??????
```

I am getting an error "Coul not expand second file name so as to match first"

Any idea on how to do a rename with multiple periods in it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Single line version:

```
for %f in ("C:\Test\X.*") do copy "%~f" "C:\Test2\DATE.%~nxf"
```

Comment: I love answers like this :) +1

Comment: Ran out of votes - been going through the top questions and stuff... I tried. Give it a few hours and I'll try again =)

Comment: Would probably be better with multiple dots in the file mask: `... in("c:\test\x.*.*") do ...`

Comment: @dbenham: Thanks, but can you explain where x.* might fail and x.*.* succeed?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - `x.*` and `x.*.*` yield the exact same result. I was intending to ignore files that did not have at least two dots. The actual solution that restricts processing to files with two or more dots requires changing to `for /f "eol=: delims=" %F in ('dir /b X.*^|findstr /i "X\..*\."') do...`

Comment: @dbenham: Gotcha. Yes, of course findstr will work with wildcards or a little regex thrown in if required if that sort of requirement is there.

Comment: There you go :)

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
xcopy C:\test\X.??????.?????? C:\test2\
ren X.??????.?????? DATE.X.??????.??????
```

First copy, then rename